# EmberJS - save with relation

Tags: ember.js

If I have a product model and items model in Ember, one product has many items. How can I save this when creating a product? 
My items is in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to push the item model in the product model or vice versa

```
product.get('items').pushObject(item);
product.save();
```

or if it is a one to many relationship

```
item.set('product', product);
item.save();
```

more info:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/models/relationships/#toc_creating-records